# A general term of this sequence

Tags: list-manipulation, homework

My question is about the set theory.
I have `c[0]={{1}}` and i want to define `c[n]` as follows:

```
c[n] = Prepend 1 to each element of c[n-1] UNION add 1 to the first element of each element of c[n-1].
```

For example:

```
c[1]={{1,1},{2}}

c[2]={{1,1,1},{2,1},{1,2},{3}}

c[3]={{1,1,1,1},{2,1,1},{1,2,1},{3,1},{1,1,2},{2,2},{1,3},{4}}
```

Please help me with this homework assignment.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. What have you tried? Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) accordingly. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) it will inspire great answers.

Comment: Did you search the site for similar questions? Did you find [190310](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190310), [126150](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126150), [224738](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224738)? Why do those questions' answers don't answer yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend has an curried form:

```
Prepend[1] /@ {{a, b}, {c, d, e}}
(* outputs {{1, a, b}, {1, c, d, e}} *)
```

MapAt can be used to apply a function to parts of a list:

```
MapAt[1 + # &, {{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {All, 1}]
(* {{1 + a, b}, {1 + c, d, e}} *)
```

The function Union does unions. So, we have a pretty straightforward implementation:

```
c[0] = {{1}};
c[n_] := Union[Prepend[1] /@ c[n - 1], MapAt[1 + # &, c[n - 1], {All, 1}]]
```

It might be worth adding checks to avoid calculating c[n] with negative or non-integer n. It might also be worth using some memoization. These choices would depend on your context.

Comment: Great Thanks for your help Dear @lericr.